# Pass parameter to predicate with Alloy Java API

Tags: java, alloy

How can I create an instance of atom with Alloy API? My goal is create an instance from java and pass it as a parameter to predicate alloy model.

The issue is:
`Field "field (this/File <: name)" is not bound to a legal value during translation.`

Would you let me know how to fix the problem?

My model look like this:

```
sig Name{}

sig File{
    name: Name
}

pred checkName[f: File]{
    f.name in Name
}
```

I define signatures:

```
PrimSig name = new PrimSig("Name");

PrimSig file = new PrimSig("File");
Field fileNameField = file.addField("name", name);
```

I create instance:

```
PrimSig myName = new PrimSig(name, "Name");

PrimSig myFile = new PrimSig(file, "File");
myFile.addField("name", name);
myFile.join(fileNameField).equal(myName);
```

I run the command:

```
Expr expr = CompUtil.parseEverything_fromFile(rep, null, improvementModelPath).getAllFunc().get(0).call(myFile);
Command cmd = new Command(false, 3, 3, 3, expr);
A4Solution sol = TranslateAlloyToKodkod.execute_command(NOP, sigs, cmd, opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean API for this, at least as far as I know.

In general I just use source code for this. I.e. if I want a command I add it to the source and then lookup the command from the CompModule.

To see some example, here is the upcoming [Evaluator](https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/blob/master/org.alloytools.alloy.cli/src/main/java/org/alloytools/alloy/cli/Evaluator.java), part of the command line interface in the upcoming release.

I once started to work on a clean API but too many things to do.